# Accessing nested JSON object in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, api, typescript-typings

I'm accessing an API, and I get some data like :

```
const article = response.data;
const articleId = article.id;
const longTitle = article.items[1].objet.long_title;
const date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(new Date(article.items[1].objet.date));
```

And when I defined a TypeScript interface like :

```
interface Article {
    id: number;
    longTitle: string;
    date: Date;
}
```

And use it like :

```
response => {
    const article: Article = response.data;
    const articleId = article.id;
    const longTitle = article.items[1].objet.long_title;
    const date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-FR').format(new Date(article.items[1].objet.date));
}
```

I get a compilation error saying :
Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Article'.ts(2339)

How can I get the data without changing the interface, is there any other solution, please?

Can I achive that with class-transformer?

[class-transfomer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)

Regards

Comment: `(article as any).items` will work if you can't modify `interface Article`

Comment: If you can edit the Article interface, can't you just add a "items" array as a property? For example `items: Item[]`, and create an interface for the item type.